# Вопрос по работе netsnmp (snmpwalk) при смене community в python

Tags: python

Потребовалось написать простой скрипт на python который бы получал данные по snmp с сетевых устройств.
Но проблема появилась в том, что на некоторых устройствах могут быть разные community, пытаюсь реализовать проверку но, что то идет нет так, при запуске если первый community не правильный то, второй запуск возвращает пустоту.
Кто нибудь может подсказать как это поправить ?

```
ip = '10.255.101.190'
community = 'public'
community1 = 'public1'

oids = netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1'))


def snmp_con(oid, ip_1, community_1):
    print(oid,ip_1,community_1)
    snmp_res = netsnmp.snmpwalk(oid, Version=2, DestHost=ip_1, Community=community_1)
    return snmp_res

snmp = snmp_con(oids,ip,community)
if snmp == ():
    snmp = snmp_con(oids,ip,community1)

print(snmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Переделал все в такой вид и добавил в функции таймаут 1 секунду и все начало работать, подскажите на сколько данный код нормальный или можно как то по другому реализовать ?

```
oid1 = netsnmp.Varbind('.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1')


def snmp_con(oid, ip_1, community_1):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(oid,ip_1,community_1)
    snmp_res = netsnmp.snmpwalk(oid, Version=2, DestHost=ip_1, Community=community_1)
    return snmp_res

snmp = snmp_con(oid1,ip,community1)
if snmp == ():
    snmp = snmp_con(oid1,ip,community)

print(snmp)
```